# Styling Own Button

Tags: css

I want to style my own button. I've managed to get rid of the default style, but now I want to add a thin blue border around it, but don't know how. If I just get rid of the border: none, then the default style comes back, which is not what I want
This is my style.css:

```
input#hideshow{
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 2px 0px 2px 8px;
    color: #4D7782;
    font-size:18px;
    background: #D3ECE5;
    border-color: #7BC2E3; //not showing up though
    width: 280px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: try like this border:1px solid #7BC2E3; and remove border:none from your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to specify [`border-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style) because it's default value is `none` [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Tde4m/3/).

But the easiest way is to use the [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) short hand and also specify 
[`border-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-width):

```
border:1px solid #7BC2E3;
```

and remove `border:none;`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Tde4m/)**

*CSS :*

```
input#hideshow{
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 2px 0px 2px 8px;
    color: #4D7782;
    font-size:18px;
    background: #D3ECE5;
    border:1px solid #7BC2E3;
    width: 280px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

U just specified the border color alone. U forget to specify border width

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/6tUB4/1/)

```
border: 2px solid #7BC2E3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS works perfectly. But you don't want it to work this way. You set `border` to `none` so no border is displayed. You better should set to, for instance:

```
border: 1px solid #7BC2E3;
```

And remove the `border-color` line.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
input#hideshow{
    margin: 0;
    border:1px solid blue;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 2px 0px 2px 8px;
    color: #4D7782;
    font-size:18px;
    background: #D3ECE5;
    border-color: #7BC2E3; //not showing up though
    width: 280px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3mga3/)**

`border:1px solid #7BC2E3;`

and remove

`border:none` from your code